# Which user account to use for service?

Tags: windows-services

I am creating a utility that runs as a service and starts applications. As long as I log in as an admin and start the service it will run the applications. I log out and the service (and applications) continue to run. But, if another user logs in with different credentials they cannot access the front end GUI of the applications started by the service utility.

I was wondering if there is a built in account which I could use that may solve the issue? Or if anyone has any ideas or insight in the matter?

Comment: Yes. It's called a 3-tier application. You should redesign your app.

Comment: How does your GUI communicate to the services?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Services can only be set to "interactive" when run in the system account. Notice the placement of the "Allow service to interact with desktop" checkbox on the Log On tab when configuring the service (via the Control Panel Services application).

Beyond that, are the other users logging in via RDP? Run mstsc with the "/admin" flag to ensure that they are going to Session 0 where the service will display its windows.

And finally, beware interactive services! You are probably on Windows XP or 2003 which is why it kind-of works, but Windows Vista, 7 and 2008 behave very differently (search for "Session 0 isolation").